# Inferring logic in constructor

Tags: architecture, constructor

Is it good practice to infer any kind of function in an objects constructor? For example, whether its an existing object or a new one?

I have a class where depending on the constructor used, it's either pulled from the DB, or created from scratch. I'm using C# but that's not important to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to put the custom logic in client's class which is used to create instances or use factory method instead of constructor for complex logic http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, calling virtual methods leads to undefined behaviour - as base constructor is invoked before derived one - and you shouldn't do that.

The rest depends. Method invoked from constructor could cause side-effects. For example, if you subscribe to an event in constructor and your handler is called before constructor is over. Constructor is mostly indented to set up initial values for class members.

It should be fine to call internal initialization methods, but in general I'd suggest to avoid it.

If there is some complicated initialization logic, probably you should check "Builder" pattern.